# Elasticsearch average number of clicks by user by month

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get the average number of monthly clicks per user with `Elasticsearch`.

My schema:

```
 {
    firstname,
    lastname,
    clicks: {
        user_id,
        clicked_at
    }
 }
```

My code:

```
"aggs" : {
    "avg_clicks_over_time" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
            "field" : "clicks.clicked_at",
            "interval" : "month",
            "aggs": {
                "clicks_by_user": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "clicks.user_id"
                    }
                },
                "avg_clicks_by_user": {
                    "avg_bucket": {
                        "buckets_path": "clicks_by_user>_count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible what I'm trying to do? If so, is it best way to do? And most important thing is that is this going to work what I expect?
If not do you know how can I proceed ?

Comment: The syntax of your pipeline aggregation is not correct, you're missing the `avg_bucket` section and the `aggs` section in one level too deep inside `date_histogram`. Also this is not going to get you what you expect

Comment: @Val Hi, thanks for your answer, I though if I put the aggs 1 level less deeper as you suggest (same level of date_histogram) theses aggregations will not be by month aggregated by month. Do you know how can I proceed to get the average number of monthly clicks per user? Thanks!